# VueJS3, How to parse a csv file in my src folder?

Tags: csv, webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

I am using VueJS3 cli. New in VueJS here :)

I have a csv file in my folder:

```
/src/db/example.csv
```

I would like to load it and use it as data structure, in the same way I do it with json files:

```js
import jsonExample from "@/db/example.json";
```

If I try to do it with a csv file I get this:

```js
import csvExample from "@/db/example.csv";
// You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I tried to install the `csv-loader`

```
yarn add csv-loader
```

But I don't know where to add the configuration (https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-loader#user-content-usage) I don't have any webpack configuration file :/, I have:

```
babel.config.js
jsconfig.json
package.json
vue.config.js
yarn.lock
```

I also tried to use `papaparse` directly:

```js
this.$papa.parse("@/db/example.csv");
```

But I get this error:

```json
{
  "data": [
    [
      "@/db/exaple.csv"
    ]
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "Delimiter",
      "code": "UndetectableDelimiter",
      "message": "Unable to auto-detect delimiting character; defaulted to ','"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "delimiter": ",",
    "linebreak": "\n",
    "aborted": false,
    "truncated": false,
    "cursor": 19
  }
}
```

Obviously it is interpreting the Path as a the Data.

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack

Comment: Btw it is not just about parsing. You need to decide whether you want that data to be part of your app bundle (when the data change you need to rebuild) or loaded on demand directly to the browser and then parsed (in which case you don't need to rebuild the app if CSV file changes). Each case requires quite a different solution

Comment: @MichalLevý yes, the file should be part of the bundle. It is a static data structure. And yes, if the data changes I have to rebuild the app

Comment: Thanks @MichalLevý I posted an answer based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

Following instructions here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack

I configured the loader like this:

```js
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // csv-loader
    config.module
      .rule('csv-loader')
      .test(/\.csv$/)
      .use('csv-loader')
        .loader('csv-loader')
        .end()
  }
})
```

Now this is working:

```
import data from "@/db/example.csv";
```

PD: I had to restart `yarn serve`